# CSS pseudo ::before not working on an Icon element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML that looks like this:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="newsTimePeriod item-One">
        <h3>News</h3>
        <i class="fas fa-car"></i>       
    <div class="aboutItem">
        <p>Fire is the rapid oxidation of a material
            in the exothermic chemical process of combustion,
            releasing heat, light, and various reaction products.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="newsTimePeriod item-Two">
        <h3>Old News</h3> 
        <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
    <div class="aboutItem">
        <p>Water is an inorganic with the chemical formula H 20.
            It is a transparent, tastless, odorless, and nearly
            colorless chemical substance.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I trying to display a vertical line to the icon (fa-car) and connect it to the next icon. If it is the last icon, then the vertical line does not get displayed. For example
[something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Rwl.png)

For some reason the vertical line does not work with my current CSS.

```
.newsTimePeriod {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
}

.newsTimePeriod h3{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
}

.fa-car, .aboutItem{
    margin: 18px 0px 0px 18px;
}

.fa-car {
    border-radius: 13px;
    height: 29px;
    width: 29px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #001277;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.aboutItem {
    padding: 14px 14px 14px 14px;
    max-width: 570px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DBDADA;
    color: #000;
}
/* To display vertical line*/
.fa-car::before {
    content: '';
     position: absolute;
     height: calc(100% + 28px);
     width: 3px;
     background: #33004e;
     margin-top: 30px;
     margin-left: 6px;
    
}
/* To hide vertical line on the last icon*/
.newsTimePeriod:last-child .fa-car::before {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .newsTimePeriod {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .newsTimePeriod .aboutItem {
        width: 70%;
        align-self: end;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .newsTimePeriod h3  {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        padding: 0 0 0 22px;
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I wrapped the icon class inside a `div`, then the vertical line CSS works, but I don't want the icons class wrapped inside a div.

Is there something wrong with my CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but I made a simple demo to try it and I think the main issue is the positioning. If the `::before`'s parent, the `i` tag isn't positioned relatively, giving it absolute positioning will make it's position be placed according to the whole page. Also, you can use `:not()` to select all except the last child.

```css
.box {
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  /*give the icon a position of relative*/
  position: relative; 
}

.box:not(:last-child) > .icon::before {
    content: '';
    /*now this will be sized according to the size of the icon*/
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% + 28px);
    width: 3px;
    background: #33004e;
    /*then use top or left, and % units to center it*/
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="box"><i class="icon"></i></div>
    <div class="box"><i class="icon"></i></div>
    <div class="box"><i class="icon"></i></div>
    <div class="box"><i class="icon"></i></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I know it works if the icon is wrapped inside a div class. But I am trying to get it to work without it being wrapped inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

might mbe you need this

```html
<div>
    <div class="newsTimePeriod item-One">
        <h3>News</h3>
        <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="aboutItem">
            <p>
                Fire is the rapid oxidation of a material
        in the exothermic chemical process of combustion,
        releasing heat, light, and various reaction products.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsTimePeriod item-Two">
        <h3>Old News</h3>
        <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="aboutItem">
            <p>
                Water is an inorganic with the chemical formula H 20.
        It is a transparent, tastless, odorless, and nearly
        colorless chemical substance.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.newsTimePeriod {
display: flex;
position: relative;
/* overflow: hidden; */
padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
}

.newsTimePeriod h3 {
width: 100px;
float: left;
display: flex;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    width: 3px;
    height: calc(100% - 50%);
    background-color: #33004e;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 142px;
}

.fa-car,
.aboutItem {
margin: 18px 0px 0px 18px;
}

.fa-car {
border-radius: 13px;
height: 29px;
width: 29px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #001277;
padding: 5px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top: 12px;
position: relative; /* Add position relative to keep the pseudo-element inside */
}

.aboutItem {
padding: 14px 14px 14px 14px;
max-width: 570px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #DBDADA;
color: #000;
}

/* To display vertical line */
.fa-car::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
height: calc(100% + 28px);
width: 3px;
background: #33004e;
top: 23px; /* Updated top value to align with the icons */
left: 22px; /* Updated left value to align with the icons */
}

/* To hide vertical line on the last icon */
.newsTimePeriod:last-child .line {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.newsTimePeriod {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.newsTimePeriod .aboutItem {
    width: 70%;
    align-self: end;
    margin: auto;
}
.newsTimePeriod h3 {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    padding: 0 0 0 22px;
}

/* Update for responsive view on small screens */
.fa-car::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 22px;
    height: 100%;
}
.line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    width: 3px;
    height: calc(100% - 30%);
    background-color: #33004e;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 44px;
}


}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: two questions. Why did you create a "line" div to display the line? Was  it not possible to display the line using the .fa-car::before class itself? Also, why did you wrap the html code inside a <div>, is that  necessary?

Comment: The "line" div serves the purpose of positioning the vertical line between the icon and the "aboutItem" content independently, granting precise control over its placement.

Without the "div," the CSS for the "newsTimePeriod:last-child" would not be applied. Therefore, we require the "div" element in this context.